# How to draw outline stroke on imported drawable vector?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have imported vector asset to my project from standart assets. It's code here:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M19.14,12.94c0.04,-0.3 0.06,-0.61 0.06,-0.94c0,-0.32 -0.02,-0.64 -0.07,-0.94l2.03,-1.58c0.18,-0.14 0.23,-0.41 0.12,-0.61l-1.92,-3.32c-0.12,-0.22 -0.37,-0.29 -0.59,-0.22l-2.39,0.96c-0.5,-0.38 -1.03,-0.7 -1.62,-0.94L14.4,2.81c-0.04,-0.24 -0.24,-0.41 -0.48,-0.41h-3.84c-0.24,0 -0.43,0.17 -0.47,0.41L9.25,5.35C8.66,5.59 8.12,5.92 7.63,6.29L5.24,5.33c-0.22,-0.08 -0.47,0 -0.59,0.22L2.74,8.87C2.62,9.08 2.66,9.34 2.86,9.48l2.03,1.58C4.84,11.36 4.8,11.69 4.8,12s0.02,0.64 0.07,0.94l-2.03,1.58c-0.18,0.14 -0.23,0.41 -0.12,0.61l1.92,3.32c0.12,0.22 0.37,0.29 0.59,0.22l2.39,-0.96c0.5,0.38 1.03,0.7 1.62,0.94l0.36,2.54c0.05,0.24 0.24,0.41 0.48,0.41h3.84c0.24,0 0.44,-0.17 0.47,-0.41l0.36,-2.54c0.59,-0.24 1.13,-0.56 1.62,-0.94l2.39,0.96c0.22,0.08 0.47,0 0.59,-0.22l1.92,-3.32c0.12,-0.22 0.07,-0.47 -0.12,-0.61L19.14,12.94zM12,15.6c-1.98,0 -3.6,-1.62 -3.6,-3.6s1.62,-3.6 3.6,-3.6s3.6,1.62 3.6,3.6S13.98,15.6 12,15.6z" />
</vector>
```

Simply i just want to add black stroke to it. Can i do it somehow through this xml file or i can do it only programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strokeWidth` and `strokeColor`  in `path` to add stroke to vector drawable.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="@color/black"
        android:pathData="M19.14,12.94c0.04,-0.3 0.06,-0.61 0.06,-0.94c0,-0.32 -0.02,-0.64 -0.07,-0.94l2.03,-1.58c0.18,-0.14 0.23,-0.41 0.12,-0.61l-1.92,-3.32c-0.12,-0.22 -0.37,-0.29 -0.59,-0.22l-2.39,0.96c-0.5,-0.38 -1.03,-0.7 -1.62,-0.94L14.4,2.81c-0.04,-0.24 -0.24,-0.41 -0.48,-0.41h-3.84c-0.24,0 -0.43,0.17 -0.47,0.41L9.25,5.35C8.66,5.59 8.12,5.92 7.63,6.29L5.24,5.33c-0.22,-0.08 -0.47,0 -0.59,0.22L2.74,8.87C2.62,9.08 2.66,9.34 2.86,9.48l2.03,1.58C4.84,11.36 4.8,11.69 4.8,12s0.02,0.64 0.07,0.94l-2.03,1.58c-0.18,0.14 -0.23,0.41 -0.12,0.61l1.92,3.32c0.12,0.22 0.37,0.29 0.59,0.22l2.39,-0.96c0.5,0.38 1.03,0.7 1.62,0.94l0.36,2.54c0.05,0.24 0.24,0.41 0.48,0.41h3.84c0.24,0 0.44,-0.17 0.47,-0.41l0.36,-2.54c0.59,-0.24 1.13,-0.56 1.62,-0.94l2.39,0.96c0.22,0.08 0.47,0 0.59,-0.22l1.92,-3.32c0.12,-0.22 0.07,-0.47 -0.12,-0.61L19.14,12.94zM12,15.6c-1.98,0 -3.6,-1.62 -3.6,-3.6s1.62,-3.6 3.6,-3.6s3.6,1.62 3.6,3.6S13.98,15.6 12,15.6z" />

</vector>
```

Also remove  `android:tint` as it will also change stroke color to white.